# Variable holding a sql money data type doesn't update (C#)

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, sqldatatypes, type-equivalence

I have a column type money in my sql server database, which is `moneyAcumulated`. Then with a `command` object I execute a store procedure that -among others things- brings the value for the column `moneyAcumulated`. Then in the while loop I store in variables all the values for each column the store procedure returns.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("getTickets", Connection.getConnection());
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            string bet = "";
            decimal moneyAcumulated = 0.0M;
            string id= "";
            string name = "";
            int cod = -1;
            decimal prize = 0.0M;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                bet = reader.GetString(0);
                moneyAcumulated = reader.GetDecimal(1); // This variable doesn't chage its value
                name = reader.GetString(2);
                id = reader.GetString(3);
                cod = reader.GetInt32(4);
            }
```

First time while loop iterates each variable takes the correct value (including `moneyAcumulated` that brings the `reader`, but second time `moneyAcumulated` doesn't change its value and the others do, why?

Comment: Have you had a look at the result set in Management Studio? The value may well be the same for all rows. Also, you're storing values in all rows in the same variables. You may want to use a list or something similar to hold each row.

Comment: Yes, while I was debugging I made a query (`select * from Money`) in each iteration to see the value for the column `moneyAcumulated` and it changes in the database, but not in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the SqlDataReader load all the data returned by the `command.ExecuteReader` in memory then if the data changes in the database, they would not change in the memory, I thought they would change every time the program execute the `reader.Read()` method, so that's why is was not working. And as the `moneyAcumulated` field in database is the same **initially** for all the tuples that confused me more, because the others were changing while `moneyAcumulated` wasn't.